# Passing a list of multiple functions as a parameter in another python function

Tags: python, function, text, parameters

I have created functions for text preprocessing namely f1: remove_punctuation, f2: remove_stop_words, f3: tokenize_doc. I want to create another function, f4 that allows user to choose any one/any 2/all functions f1, f2 & f3 (accepted as a parameter) and executed as part of f4.

Currently, the below code executes both the functions f1,f2 & f3 inside f4 as no parameter is available in argument section of f4. Can someone please help me modifying the code:

```
from txt_preprocessing.text_preprocessing import TextPreprocessor as TP
import pandas as pd
def read_input_from_file(filename):
    df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    function_list={TP.remove_punctuation:'remove_punctuation', TP.remove_stop_words:'remove_stop_words', TP.tokenize_doc:'tokenize_doc' }
    for func_i in function_list: 
        df['X']=df['X'].apply(lambda x: func_i(x,return_var_type="string"))
    df.to_csv('text_classification_output.csv')
    return df

read_input_from_file('text_classification_input.csv')
```

Note: TP is a package created from a file having f1, f2 & f3 in a class named TextPreprocessor and has a structure as:

```
class TextPreprocessor:
    .....
    def remove_punctuation
      .......
    def remove_stop_words
      .......
    def tokenize_doc
      .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that gets the user choice, and calls the other functions as appropriate.

```
def user_choice(x, return_var_type):
    choice = input("Remove punctuation, stop words, or both (p/s/b):")
    if choice in ['p', 'b']:
        x = TP.remove_punctuation(x, return_var_type)
    if choice in ['s', 'b']:
        x = TP.remove_stop_words(x, return_var_type)
    return x
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer. If i have more than 2 functions, and user had to be given a choice to select any one/any 2/all, then how can we modify the above code.

Comment: You could use a dictionary that maps inputs to functions, like `d = {'p': TP.remove_punctuation, 's': TP.remove_stop_words, 'x': TP.something_else, ...}`